# R: Iterate through csv files in igraph and create unique png file

Tags: r, csv, igraph

This may be a really dumb question, but I can't seem to figure out how to go about it. I'm using igraph in R. I currently have a script to plot data from a csv file. I'd like to create a for loop that will iterate through all the different csv files and save the plots as unique png file.

The file names are in the form of Table1.csv, Table2. csv, etc.

Comment: What do you mean, "plot as [a] unique png file"? Do you mean make one plot per csv? Or make a plot based on all the csvs? Or what?

Comment: One plot per csv. Sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `list.files` to loop through the files.

You can do something like this :

```
library(png)
library(igraph)
l.files <- list.files(patt='.*csv$')
## new device for new image version
png(file ="myplot.png")
imgs <- lapply(ll,function(x){
  relations <- read.csv(x)
  g <- graph.data.frame(relations, directed=TRUE)
  ## here I add title
  plot(g)
})
dev.off()
```